# How can i fetch starting of file name from the path with different extensions using R

Tags: r

"/D/data_DataAnalysis/Progrm/datset1/set2/genus/Huttenhower_LC8_genus_reported.tsv"
 "/c/bioinfoTools/data/mock/test/truth/file_sets/genus/Huttenhower_LC8_TRUTH.txt"

I want "Huttenhower_LC8" from two file name using R.

Similer to the python code

```
fileName_temp = a_file.split("/")[-1]
filename =  a_file.split("/")[-1][:-9]
 for another_file in all_slim_files:
    a_filename = another_file.split("/")[-1][:-18]
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "starting of file", why not just Huttenhower ? Or Huttenhower_LC8_genus for the first one ? What is you decision boundary ?

Comment: _genus is the boundary for the first file
_TRUTH  is the boundary for the second file
I want file name till the boundaries from two paths after "genus/"

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might have already solved the problem as it has been over 6 years now, but I was thinking of providing the solution.

--- Solution ---

We need to write a regular expression that captures this pattern would look something like "(Huttenhower_LC8)_.*" where .* matches any character (except a newline) 0 or more times and then use sub or gsub to apply this pattern and extract the required part.

file_paths <- c("/D/data_DataAnalysis/Progrm/datset1/set2/genus/Huttenhower_LC8_genus_reported.tsv",  "/c/bioinfoTools/data/mock/test/truth/file_sets/genus/Huttenhower_LC8_TRUTH.txt")

extracted_parts <- sub(".*(Huttenhower_LC8)_.*", "\1", basename(file_paths))
print(extracted_parts)